# Trying to show my array list in a Listbox?

Tags: c#, arrays, listbox

```
//to display my inventory array
for (int i = 0; i < arrayInventory[18]);
{
  lsbInvetory.Items.Add(arrayInventory[18]);
}
```

This code shows no errors but it will not display in the listbox.

Here is the code for the array listbox

```
  double[] arrayInventory = new double[]  // declaring & initialized single array
  {200, 50, 30, 25, 10, 10, 20, 14, 14, 10, 20, 15, 12, 20, 60, 25, 10, 10 };
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using C# for this!

Answer (score 0):

Change Like This

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayInventory.Length; i++) 
{
    lsbInvetory.Items.Add(arrayInventory[i]);
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but it gives me an error after Length); on the parenthesis and the semicolon. It says expected and possibly mistaken empty statement

Comment: @user3483609 check my updation

Comment: Still nothing. Nothing displays

Comment: when use above lines in your form. because its work for me @user3483609